# Determining when the function $f(x)=\int_{0}^x g$ is Lipschitz and finding the best Lipschitz constant when it is.

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

Let $E=(0, \infty)$ and $g \in L^{1}(E)$. Define $f\colon E \to \mathbb{R}$ by $$f(x)=\int_{0}^{x}g.$$

(a) Show that $f$ may not be Lipschitz on $E$.

(b) Prove that if $g \in L^{\infty}(E)$ then $f$ is Lipschitz, and find the best Lipschitz constant for $f$.

---

For $(a)$ at first I thought of the function $g(x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$. Then $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is not Lipschitz on ... $[0, \infty)$.  This unfortunately didn't work out because $E$ excludes the point $0$. I know that $f$ is Lipschitz on $[\epsilon, \infty)$. I can't think of another example that would work.

For (b), I can do the following: for any $a, b$ in $E$ such that $a < b$:
\begin{align*}
 |f(b)-f(a)|&=|\int_{0}^{b} g - \int_{0}^{a} g|  \\
 &\le \int_{a}^{b} |g |\\
 &\le \Vert g\Vert_{\infty} |b-a|.
\end{align*}

I suspect that $\Vert g\Vert_{\infty}$ ought to be the best possible, but how do I prove this?

Comment: Follows from Lebesgue's Differentiation Theorem.

Comment: @geetha290krm: You mean that $f$ is not Lipschitz? How exactly because I'm not seeing it.

Comment: I am saying that $\|g\|_{\infty}$ is the best Lipschitz constant.

Comment: $\sqrt{x}$ is not Lipschitz on $(0,\infty)$. If it was, its derivative, $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$ would be bounded on $(0,\infty)$, which it is clearly not.

Comment: @peek-a-boo: I see. Thank you so much.

Comment: @geetha290krm: Can you please explain your answer a little more. I'm unfortunately now following how exactly the differentiation theorem implies that that is the best constant. Thank you.

Comment: Take any Lipschitz constant $C$ and show that $\|g\|_{\infty} \leq C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq C|x-y|$ for all $x,y$. Then $\\frac 1 {b-a}\int_a^{b} g(x) dx|\leq C$ whenever $a<b$. By Lebesgue's Theorem, this implies $|g(a)| \leq C$ for almost all $a$. Hence, $\|g\|_{\infty} \leq C$.  This proves a) because there exist integrable functions $g$ with $\|g\|_{\infty}=\infty$.

We have also proved that if $C$ is a Lischitz constant for $f$ then $\|g\|_{\infty} \leq C$. Since $\|g\|_{\infty}$ is a Lipschitz constant for $f$  by your argument, it follows that it is the smallest Lipscitz constant.

Comment: I'm sorry for the incessant questioning, but can you please write the steps precisely for why $|\frac 1 {b-a}\int_a^{b} g(x) dx|\leq C$ whenever $a<b$ implies by Lebesgue's Theorem that $|g(a)| \leq C$? Everything else is super clear. Thank you for answering my question.

Comment: You don't seem to have seen that theorem. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem

Comment: Sadly I have seen it. I guess the point of confusion for me is how are we taking the derivative inside the abs. value on the left side?

Comment: What is the definition of derivative of $f$ at $a$?  @JohnSmith

Comment: I see it now. Thank you so much for your time/help.